# How to style elements inside Shadow-DOM?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a chrome-extension where I add a sahdow-DOM to a element. How do you style the elements inside shadow-DOM. More specifically, how do you select elements inside shadow-DOM in CSS?

```
 <div class="kosmikExtension-root"></div>
   #shadow-root(open)
   <div class="content>Hello, World!</div>
 </div>
```

How do I select the .content element from contentScript.css file which I have defined as content script CSS in manifest.json.

Comment: You'll have to add a stylesheet inside ShadowDOM and use relative selectors inside. See also https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/

Comment: When I type "style shadowDOM" in Google I see all resources I used to learn this.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yeah, I know but every one of them is different and I found them complex and was like 'Surely, there gotta be a easier way' and so I asked here. Some, questions I am having:
1)If I want to insert a modal on page on clicking on context-menu item(of my extension), is shadow-DOM the best idea or is there a better way. 
2)And the way of describing that modal is javascript, or is there a way to implement in HTML?